# how to get the storage location from firebaseStorage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

how can i get the storage location from firebase storage? i have an image that uploads to firebase storage it doesnt have a foldername its has a file name and that = Businessname.jpg.

this is an insert from my Adapterclass and mbusinsessicon is the filename

```
 final String mbusinessicon = mIMAGE_URL.get(position);
    Log.i("FirebaseLocation",mbusinessicon);
```

i thought something like this

```
    StorageReference firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(mbusinessicon+".jpg");

 firebaseStorage.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            String url = uri.toString();
            Log.i("URL_FOR_FIREBASEIMAGE",url);
            Glide.with(context).load(uri).into(holder.iv_icon);
        }
```

but it leaves me an errror in my logcat

```
FileNotFoundException: No such storage volume
```

Comment: What the value of `mbusinessicon`?

Comment: @AlexMamo the value of mbusinessicon is =  the filename less the .jpg